# KeyError: "The name 'ImageTensor:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'ImageTensor', does not exist in the graph."

Tags: arcgis-pro, error-999999, image-segmentation, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm trying to use ArcGIS Pro 2.3 and this tutorial (https://medium.com/geoai/high-resolution-land-cover-mapping-using-deep-learning-7126fee571dd) to use the function "**Classify Pixels Using Deep Learning**" to classify buildings. I was able to train the .h5 U-Net model, but I'm getting the following error message on the last step of the tutorial:

```
ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Contact Esri Technical Support (http://esriurl.com/support) to Report a Bug, and refer to the error help for potential solutions or workarounds.
 Unable to obtain configuration properties associated with the raster function.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "S:\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\Raster\Functions\System\DeepLearning\ImageClassifier.py", line 132, in getConfiguration
 configuration = self.child_image_classifier.getConfiguration(**scalars)
 File "s:\arcgis\pro\Resources\Raster\Functions\System\DeepLearning\Keras\DeepLab.py", line 46, in getConfiguration
 image_tensor = self.classification_graph.get_tensor_by_name('ImageTensor:0')
 File "C:\Users\Luiz\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3654, in get_tensor_by_name
 return self.as_graph_element(name, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=False)
 File "C:\Users\Luiz\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3478, in as_graph_element
 return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
 File "C:\Users\Luiz\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3520, in _as_graph_element_locked
 "graph." % (repr(name), repr(op_name)))
 KeyError: "The name 'ImageTensor:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'ImageTensor', does not exist in the graph."
 Configuration properties returned by the python raster function is not a python dictionary.
 Failed to execute (ClassifyPixelsUsingDeepLearning).
```

I believe the error is in:  **KeyError: "The name 'ImageTensor:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'ImageTensor', does not exist in the graph."**

Did anyone encounter a similar problem?